# PHP logout with Apache form authentication

Tags: php, apache, session, forms-authentication

I'm using Apache as my web server.
It is setup for form authentication with

```
<form method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
  Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I can login no problem and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is set as expected.
The back-end for the credentials is a MySQL DB.

My issue is with the logout process from my protected page.
I did digg around and there seam to be a concensur around this:

```
function logout() {
    // if ($debug) { echo "Logging out...<br />"; }
    echo "Logging out...<br />";
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
        // if ($debug) { echo "Session params: "; print_r($params); echo "<br />"; }
        echo "Session params: "; print_r($params); echo "<br />";
    }
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $is_https = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1)
        || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https';
    $url = ($is_https ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header("Location: {$url}");
}
```

Unfortunately, this just not work for me and my session is still very much alive.

I tried unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']); but that makes no difference either.

For the record, the `print_r(session_get_cookie_params());` gives me this:

```
Array ( [filemanager] => Array ( [logged] => testuser ) )
auth_users: Array ( [0] => testuser )
```

I've got to be missing something, but what?

**[Update]**

Looking very closely at what is being created on the browser side, I see that there is a cookie called 'session' that gets created with a successful login.
If I manually delete that cookie, my session ends and I have to log back in again. So THAT is the cookie I need to delete.
I tried `setcookie("session","",time()-3600);` and `unset($_COOKIE['session']);` but neither is working; too easy I guess...

*How on earth can I delete this thing?*

Note: when running `print_r($_COOKIE);`, it is there: `Array ( [session] => 79Faq7Mn3pEmTflhKWNLE5khuWX3aNF9hT3Q8AApX9VNwFKqnU6m0ii/UXCvQ4rP16DSJb7OJj2cpcrqg0U9AXxVYrsf8/NHJ9jyZGTM9nY1jPA2R3mINJyoTf991qDApoS2/0zWCuw= [fm_cache] => 1 [fileexchanger] => psrfekv0il94e1589ge0lkkoul )`

**[Update 2]**

Actually, I can delete the cookie names 'session' from my PHP code...
The thing is though, if I refresh the page, the cookie comes right back with a different id.
That session cookie is created outside my page actually as if I put `print_r($_COOKIE);` as the very first line of code in my PHP file, I can see that the 'session' cookie is there.

The ONLY explanation I can see is that it's coming from Apache...
This is from my site configuration file

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html/pathtofolder/">
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    AuthFormProvider dbd
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Restricted Server"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
    SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM table WHERE username = %s"
    ErrorDocument 401 /login.html
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

I checked it out and `SessionCookieName session path=/` is the one creating that 'session' cookie.
If I comment this line out, a simple `session_destroy();` logs me out.
Then again, that too is way too easy because now, every time I click on a link, submit a form, reload, WHATEVER, I'm redirected to the login page.

Any help would really be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean is that me? Yes, I posted this question....

Comment: Sorry, this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712559/how-can-i-log-out-of-my-website-using-php

Comment: Nope. That's not me. Didn't see that post actually... Looks like there was no answer.
It does mention that the page needs to be refreshed but that doesn't change anything. Unless I clear all the browser data I'm logged in.

Comment: Is there no solution to this? If so, why having form authentication in the first place then?